# how to send string to server to differentiate it

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 textareas in client-side.

Users type things in those textareas. What I need to do is send those 3 textareas to the server, but I want to send it just like this.

```
let allText = `${firstText}|${secondText}|${thirdText}`
```

as you can see, there's a `|` operator between them so that server can use that operator to get all 3 texts.

**Problem**: Sometimes users might type anything in textareas such as `|` or `&` or any kind of symbol. So on back-end, it seems to be a bad idea to use that operator to differentiate them.

So I can't trust any symbols. What can I do?

Comment: Don't send it like a string but as an object? Is there a reason you want to send it as one string? (To me it feels like, "I want to close my door with glue, but now I can't get it open. How can I open the door?")

Comment: Agree, i am a front-end developer, but where I work, this is the way. So that's why.

Comment: Ok use a complicated separator then such as "°S^E^P°". Now you can split in the backend onto that complicated separator. The chance that someone types that in the textarea is really small

Comment: yeah, but is not there any other way, like to encode that string somehow?

Comment: Don't use pipes.  Encode to JSON before sending, then decode on the server side (you don't indicate the server language, so can't help there - but you can use `JSON.stringify([$firstText, $secondText, $thirdText]);` then on the server you'll have an array of 3 strings once you 'json_decode` it...

Comment: You *could* take the contents of each text area, decode them into byte arrays, encode those byte arrays as base 64 strings, concatenate them with your pipe symbols and then reverse the process on the backend. Or, you could just send the data as `{ "firstText": firstText, "secondText": secondText, "thirdText": thirdText }`. One is simple and straightforward, the other complex and error prone.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, first solution iswith pipe symbols, that's what he was asking to do it without. The second solution is exactly what I said in the first comment.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili do you have any specific reason not to send it as a object. If yes, you can use a combination of symbols and then you can differentiate it

Comment: @Wimanicesir First solution was a joke, second solution was supposed to be the same as yours (I upvoted your comment). It was meant to illustrate the fact that the OP was going out of his way to complicate what should be an easy thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your backend can read JSON then you can send the string created by JSON.stringify

```js
let firstText = "he|re"
let secondText = `with"'quotes`
let thirdText = '0|<>\\^$¤£↓→ødð«æð'

let allText = JSON.stringify({ firstText, secondText, thirdText })
console.log(allText)
```

the back end will then be able to read these value separately

(example if you're using a js backend)

```js
let firstText = "he|re"
let secondText = `with"'quotes`
let thirdText = '0|<>\\^$¤£↓→ødð«æð'

let allText = JSON.stringify({ firstText, secondText, thirdText })




let received = allText
let parsed = JSON.parse(received)

console.log(parsed.firstText)
console.log(parsed.secondText)
console.log(parsed.thirdText)
```